# Bootstrap accordion is not working correctly in mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i have used bootstrap accordion in my web page .It is working fine in Chrome but it is not working in mozilla firefox.Social Sharing buttons is not displaying in mozilla firefox.Clicking on first accordion and clicking on second accordion the first one is not closing immediately only in mozilla.Unable to display social sharing icons in mozilla.

```
<div class="digitalmarketingassociate">
                  <span class="digit"><?php echo $r->job_name ;?></span>
                  <div class="applynow">Apply Now</div>
                  <div class="moreinfo accordion" >More Info</div>
                    <div class="panel">         

                            <h3 class="job">Job Description</h3>
                            <p class="jobdes"><?php echo $r->job_description ;?></p>

                            <h3 class="job">Desired Skills & Experience</h3>
                            <p class=""desiredskills"><?php echo $r->skills_experience ;?></p>

                            <h3 class="job">Educational Qualification</h3>
                            <p class="educationalqua"><?php echo $r->qualification ;?></p>

                            <h3 class="job">Roles and Responsibilities</h3>
                            <ul class="rolesand">
                                <li class="rolesandres"><?php echo $r->roles_responsibilities;?></li>
                            </ul>

                            <h3 class="job">What we offer</h3>
                            <p class="whatweoffer"><?php echo $r->what_we_offer ;?></p>


                            <h3 class="job">How to apply</h3>
                            <p class="howtoapp">Email us your resume along with your Linkedin profile on <a href="mailto:hrmanager@xxxx.com" class="hrmanager">hrmanager@xxxx.com</a> with subject line in the following format:<br/>
                            Position Applied for | Total Experience | Any two top skills | Expected Monthly Salary<br/>
                            Alternatively, you can also apply via <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/images/testimonial/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" /></p>

                            <h3  class="job">Share this job</h3>                

                            <div class="facebookaccount"><div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo base_url()?>career/careers/<?php echo $r ->jobs_name ;?>"data-layout="button_count"></div></div>
                            <div class="twitteraccount"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script></div>
                            <div class="linkedinaccount"><span class="linkedincount"><script type="IN/Share" data-url="<?php echo base_url()?>career/careers/<?php echo $r ->jobs_name ;?>" data-counter="right"></script></span></div>
                            <div class="googleaccount"><div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-height="24" data-href="<?php echo base_url()?>career/careers/<?php echo $r ->jobs_name ;?>"></div></div>

                    </div>

                </div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].onclick = function(){
   this.classList.toggle("active");
   this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
 }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: what version of firefox you are using and can you share jsfiddle / github link of your code

Comment: 53.0.3(32 bit) version

Comment: The code you provided does not give any clue on what could be the cause. You need add a [mcve] of your issue here, using the snippet button (`<>`) and making sure it recreates the issue, limiting the code to only what is strictly necessary for the question being asked.

Comment: Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/2kq91unp/

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu actually i have used bootstrap accordion but the proble is the accordion is not working in mozilla browser and the social sharing buttons is not displaying in mozilla browser this is the issue which i am facing

Comment: Actually, you have not used anything, because you pasted the `<script>` tags inside the "external resources" box, instead of just pasting the links (i.e.: `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js`). None of the scripts you're tying to use loads properly. That's your problem. You're a bit behind on basics here. Try to look at some examples, go over some tutorials, maybe...!?

Comment: And you have errors in your HTML. Run your source through the HTML validator at http://validator.w3.org and correct all the issues it finds. Or just glance at JSFiddle's syntax highlighting.